# "Is it possible to follow Lick to 'some path url' only after second click ?"

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have `Link to="some_url"`, when I hover on, It shows some text but in mobile version user can't hover it so I need to do something like `'first click: shows text like hover'` and `'second click follow the link'`

```
 <SlickSlider {...sliderSettings}>
            {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(item => (
              <Link
                key={item}
                to={...}
                onClick={handleCloseModal}
              >
              {children}
              </Link>
            ))}
          </SlickSlider>
```

Comment: ... so have you attempted to solve the problem yourself? We are not here to write your code for you.

Comment: Yes,  I have.  But I suppose it was wrong way.  Maybe some one have best practices for this task.

Comment: Best practice questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Don't miss your time. Leave this question

Answer (score 1):

I guess I am close to answer your question or answer all of this your query. I am not masterful at JavaScript. so sorry for possible mistake, but I think this source code works I hope.

React.JS source code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import withRouter from 'react-router-dom/withRouter';

class Example extends Component {
   state = {
    activeHover: false, 
    countDownToRedirect: 0
    };


    handleRedirectToAwesomeUrl = () =>{
        let messageShowedUpAlready = this.state.countDownToRedirect >= 2;

        if (messageShowedUpAlready) {
            this.props.history.push('/awesome');
        }
    };

    showDiffText = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let countdownValue =  this.state.countDownToRedirect;
        const incCountdown = countdownValue++;
        this.setState({activeHover: true, countDownToRedirect: countdownValue})
    };

    showNormalText = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ activeHover: false });
    };

    render(){
      return (
       <div>
         <button onClick={this.handleRedirectToAwesomeUrl}
                                onMouseEnter={this.showDiffText}
                                onMouseLeave={this.showNormalText}>
                         { this.state.activeHover ? 
                         <span>Text</span> : <span>Another different text</span> }
         </button>
       <div>
      );
    }

}


export default withRouter(Example);
```

If you had any questions, ask any on them.